# Cannot implicitly convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Employee>'

Tags: c#, json.net

I have the following code:

```
public EmployeeDepartment InsertEmployeeAndDepartment(params dynamic[] employee)
{                
    filteredEmployees.EmployeeRecords = employee[0];           
}
```

Where **EmployeeRecords** is of type `IEnumerable<Employee>`

I am getting the following exception:

> *Cannot implicitly convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)*

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Why is employee dynamic[]? This is gonna cause all sorts of problems like say is someone passes a jObject in instead of a IList<Employee>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message suggests that `employee[0]` is being returned as a `JObject`, so it has to be parsed in order to be cast to another type of object.  I haven't seen enough of your code to know which one will work best for you, and you may have more steps to take, but something like the Dynamic to Strong Type Mapping (using `JObject.ToObject()`) or Strongly Typed JSON Parsing (using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()`) as described on the following page should put you on the right path:

http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Aug/30/Using-JSONNET-for-dynamic-JSON-parsing#DynamictoStrongTypeMapping

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer. In my case I wanted to convert the JObject to a dynamic, then convert the dynamic to an IDictionary<string, object> so I could work with the names like obj["[Field Name]"]. I had to use JObject.ToObject<IDictionary<string, object>>(). Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [JavascriptSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to convert your dynamic into Employee :

```
public EmployeeDepartment InsertEmployeeAndDepartment(params dynamic[] employee)
{         
    var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();       
    filteredEmployees.EmployeeRecords = serializer.Deserialize<List<EmployeeRecords >>(employee);           
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Uhm you are trying to assing a single employee to an enumerable. Try:

```
filteredEmployees.EmployeeRecords = employee;
```

Is there any good reason why you are using a dynamic parameter on that method?

If you want just one element in your enumerable you can try:

```
filteredEmployees.EmployeeRecords = new [] { employee[0] };
```

Although I suspect you will need at some point to deserialize the JSON object into a Employee object

Comment: "employee"  an array ..i have to ultimately do filteredEmployees.EmployeeRecords = employee[0] and filteredEmployees.DeptRecords = employee[1];