# Get Api flurl.http method used

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am calling a APi using Flurl.http that contains Value and Text field.
I am using that api in Picker !

```
async void method()
        {
            string url = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/api/QMSRejection/GetShiftMaster";
            IList<dynamic> list = await url.GetJsonListAsync();
            var modelList = new List<string>();
            
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                modelList.Add(item.Text);
                
            }
            ShiftPicker.ItemsSource = modelList;

        }
```

this is json response api provides

```
{"Value":"SF2017-1","Text":"General Shift Head Office"},{"Value":"SF2017-2","Text":"Shift-A-1 (Day)"},{"Value":"SF2017-3","Text":"Shift-B-1 (Night)"},{"Value":"SF2017-4","Text":"Shift-C"},{"Value":"SF2017-5","Text":"Shift-9.00AM-6.00PM"},{"Value":"SF201711","Text":"Morning Shift (6.00 Am-3.00Pm)"},{"Value":"SF20171203","Text":"Shift 6:30AM to 3:00PM"},{"Value":"SF2018-1","Text":"General Shift Factory-1"},{"Value":"SF20182","Text":"Shift 10AM to 8PM"},{"Value":"SF20191","Text":"General Shift Factory-2"},{"Value":"SF20192","Text":"Shift 7:00AM to 4:00PM"},{"Value":"SF20193","Text":"Shift-A-2 (Day)"},{"Value":"SF20194","Text":"Shift-B-2 (Night)"}]
```

I am getting data correctly and I am able to fetch selected Item as well but issue is that I have added only text field but I need access of Value Field as well !

Right now When I have to pass selected value of dropdown, I only have text and I need associated value field with it too so I can use it!
I will display only text but I need access of it !

Comment: How can I solve it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @Iria suggested, first define a model class for your data

```
public class MyClass{
  public string Value{get;set;}
  public string Text{get;set}
}
```

then tell flurl to return a strongly typed class instead of using dynamic

```
var data = await url.GetJsonAsync<List<MyClass>>();
```

then you can bind your picker directly to data

```
ShiftPicker.ItemsSource = data;
```

Comment: in the dropdown it is showing me something like this : ProjectName.Views.FormName+ Myclass. For all records showing this so as I have 13 rows I am receiving 13 values like this !

Comment: if you read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/populating-itemssource) you would know you need to set the ItemDisplayBinding property

Comment: yup ItemDisplayBinding worked for me ! Thanks ! You are great !

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

```
var results = await url.GetJsonListAsync();
var myClass =  JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<MyClass>>(results);
```

Then

```
public class MyClass{
public string Value{get;set;}
public string Text{get;set}
}
```

in myClass you have a collection of objects that have Value and Text, then you have the correspondance between value and Text for each object

Comment: it gives me an error "Cann't convert from system.collections.generic.IList<dynamic> to Newtonsoft.JsonReader"

Comment: instead of using dynamic, use my definition of MyClass, by the way, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29541415/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-newtonsoft-json-linq-jobject-to-system-collect

Comment: var results= await url.GetJsonListAsync();                                                                       
var myClass = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<MyClass>>(results); I  have used this like u mentioned but it is giving error I mentioned before !

Comment: what is results? are you getting back the json list over there?

Comment: yes as u did ! It is showing that error in results variable ! yes i m getting json list in results variable !

Comment: you need to pass the raw json string to Deserialize() - it appears that you are doing some other processing inside of GetJsonListAsync()

Comment: string url = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/api/QMSRejection/GetShiftMaster";                         
  var results= await url.GetJsonListAsync();
       
  var myClass = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<MyClass>>(results);                  I did this as she mentioned !

Comment: what is the return type of GetJsonListAsync?  @Iria assumes it is a string, but clearly it is not

Comment: it is clear that something has changed at some point, do you have version control?

Comment: I didn't got your point ! Can you describe in more detail ?